# How to push the last commit to Github after I have made subsequent changes?

Tags: xcode, git, github, commit

- I committed my Xcode project to the local git repository.
- I hadn't yet pushed the project to github.
- I continued to work on the code substantially without making another commit. It is currently not ready for another commit.
- At this point, is it possible to push the last committed version to github without all the subsequent changes I made? If so, how do I do it from within Xcode?

Comment: I would suggest googling "stash changes Xcode"

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below 3 commands ;

1. git stash (This will temporarily shelve your changes, leaving your branch to the last commit you made. You can still get all your subsequent changes back )
2. git push origin branch-name
3. git stash apply ( To get all the subsequent changes back)

Hope this answers your question. Happy coding !!!